# How do I dynamically size images to fit inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that contains the search results of a query. I want all of the images that are results of the query to fit inside the div without any scrolling (aka I want the images to scale down as far as they can so that they all fit inside)

Here is a screenshot so you can get a better idea.

[image]

and then when i have 25 results:

[image]

Again, I do not care how small the images get, i just want them all to scale down so that they will fit inside the results container.

Comment: Try with the: `img {display: block; width: auto; height: auto; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100vh}`

Comment: `width: auto; height: auto;` shouldn't be necessary if `display:block;`.

Comment: Also without the `display: block`, just a habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IS this what you're looking for? You can make use of flexbox to achieve that. If you want to wrap a certain amount of images only in a single row, say 10 images per row. Then you can make use of these additional styles applied to both the tags:

```
#container {
flex-flow:row wrap;
}
#container > img{
width:10%; //100% / 10% = 10 images per row if the images are of same dimensions
}
```

```css
#container {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#container>img {
  background: red;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Oh this is so close. The first version of the comment you made worked perfectly, the row wrapping makes the images to large, i am working with it now

Comment: I just added those 2 styles additionally in case you wanted to wrap it. You can just ignore the flex-flow and the width setting of the img if you don't need them.

Comment: @KyleBrown Seeing that as it is the only answer, rate it up and mark if this helped. Cheers